# Losing "next line" formatting when populating JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, format

I have an ArrayList containing Strings called responseList:

```
ArrayList<String> responseList;
```

I also have a JTextField called responseField:

```
JTextField responseField;
```

The ArrayList is populated with varying lines of plaintext strings. For instance, responseList.get(0) would contain something along the lines of:

```
cat mouse hello world
dog kitten puppy potatoes
carrot beef kryptonite
```

Simple enough. However, this is where the discrepancy occurs. When I do:

```
System.out.println(responseList.get(0));
```

I get, as expected:

```
cat mouse hello world
dog kitten puppy potatoes
carrot beef kryptonite
```

Strangely enough, when I do:

```
 responseField.setText(responseList.get(0));
```

the responseField element in my Swing GUI displays it as:

```
cat mouse hello worlddog kitten puppy potatoescarrot beef kryptonite
```

The new line characters don't seem to be read in. JTextField is interpreting my original text differently than Eclipse's console output does.

Can I get some explanation on why JTextField's setText(String) strips my text of new lines? And further, how to remedy this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe JTextArea is a better choice in this case since JTextField is intended to show a single line of text. From [JTextField API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html): *"`JTextField` is a lightweight component that allows the editing of a **single line of text**."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the responseField variable to be a JTextArea instead of JTextField: a JTextField contains, by definition, only one line.

Comment: Hey, that did the trick! It slipped my mind that JTextArea was a much better choice for blocks of text, so my mind kind of defaulted to JTextField. Knowledge of API is so important. Thanks again.